# Restrict ble peripheral application to connect with only one central

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a ble peripheral application in android and ios, i am also facing an issue like, my android/ios peripheral application is advertising and it got connected with the master (central ) and another central application is getting connected with my peripheral application, hence the data transfer between my application and master( central ) is getting disturbed. Can anyone please suggest a way to restrict my application to get connected with only one central at a time.

Thanks in advance.